# Trying to close popup by clicking outside of div breaks button that opened it

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, navigation

I have a mobile/responsive nav menu that is opened with a button using jquery. The button was working great until I added a jquery script to also close the window if the user clicks anywhere outside of the menu div, that script also works as intended to close the menu everywhere except when attempting to use the initial menu button, which won't function if I try to close the menu with it (but can still be used to open the menu again if its closed).

Anyone able to help me figure out why the button itself isnt working?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var mobileNav = $('#mobile-nav');

    //Toggle hide on the menu
    $('.btn-navbar').on('click', function(){
      mobileNav.toggleClass('d-none');
    });

    // Hide menu if clicked outside
    $(document).mouseup(function(e){
      if (!mobileNav.is(e.target) && mobileNav.has(e.target).length === 0 && !mobileNav.hasClass('d-none')){
        $('#mobile-nav').toggleClass('d-none');
      }

    });
     
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `mouseup` event fires before `click` event, so when you click on `.btn-navbar` actually first the handler related to `mouseup` runs, and it toggles the class `d-none` on `mobileNav`, after that the handler related to click runs, and it again toggles the `d-none` class on `mobileNav`, so as a result it's display never changes, to solve them problem,in the `mouseup` handler you can check if the target element is not `.btn-navbar` then toggle `d-none` class, like this:

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
  if (!$(e.target).is('.btn-navbar') && !mobileNav.is(e.target) && mobileNav.has(e.target).length === 0 && !mobileNav.hasClass('d-none')){
    $('#mobile-nav').toggleClass('d-none');
  }
});
```

Here is a simple example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mobileNav = $('#mobile-nav');

  //Toggle hide on the menu
  $('.btn-navbar').on('click', function() {
    mobileNav.toggleClass('d-none');
  });

  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.btn-navbar') && !mobileNav.is(e.target) && mobileNav.has(e.target).length === 0 && !mobileNav.hasClass('d-none')) {
      $('#mobile-nav').toggleClass('d-none');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none
}

#mobile-nav {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-navbar">Toggle nav</button>
<h1 id="mobile-nav" class="d-none">nav content</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not certain of the why but the button doesn't like the $(document) declaration ... i'm now using the same function but using the id of the main content div

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this style to the class of your button. Seems like it was causing a conflict with the click event.

```
pointer-events: none;
```